# Storing Sessions in database - data being overwritten

Tags: php, session

somewhere, something is causing an empty session to be written to my database.

I've recently implemented the change to using Zend/Db, and it's only after this that I'm having the issue.

Here's my read function

```
public function read($sessionId)
{

    $sql = new Sql($this->database);
    $predicate = new Where();

    $query = $sql->select();
    $query->from('sessions');
    $query->columns(array('sessiondata'));
    $query->where($predicate->equalTo('sessionid', $sessionId));
    $query->where($predicate->greaterThan('expiry', new Expression("NOW()")));

    /**
     * @var $stmt \Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\StatementInterface;
     */

    $stmt = $sql->prepareStatementForSqlObject($query);
    $result = $stmt->execute();


    if ($result instanceof ResultInterface && $result->isQueryResult() && $result->getAffectedRows() > 0) {
        $resultSet = new ResultSet;
        $resultSet->initialize($result);

        $data = $resultSet->toArray();
        return $data[0]['sessiondata'];
    } else {
        echo "read_fail";
        return false;
    }
}
```

And my write function

```
public function write($sessionId, $sessionData)
{

    $expiry = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time() + CATALINA_MAX_SESSION_TIME - 1);


    $sql = new Sql($this->database);
    $query = $sql->select()
        ->from('sessions')
        ->columns(
            array(
                'sessionid'
            )
        )
        ->where(
            array(
                'sessionid' => $sessionId
            )
        );

    /**
     * @var $stmt \Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\StatementInterface;
     */

    $stmt = $sql->prepareStatementForSqlObject($query);
    $result = $stmt->execute();

    $sql = new Sql($this->database);

    if ($result->count() > 0) {

        $query = $sql->update('sessions')
            ->set(array(
                        'expiry' => new Expression("NOW() + interval 1 hour"),
                        'touch' => new Expression("NOW()"),
                        'sessiondata' => $sessionData
                )
        )
            ->where(array('sessionid' => $sessionId));

    } else {

        $query = $sql->insert()
            ->into('sessions')
            ->columns(
                array(
                    'sessionid',
                    'expiry',
                    'sessiondata'
                )
            )
            ->values(
                array(
                    'sessionid' => $sessionId,
                    'expiry' => $expiry,
                    'sessiondata'=> $sessionData
                )
            );
    }

    $stmt = $sql->prepareStatementForSqlObject($query);
    $result = $stmt->execute();
}
```

Am I missing something here which is causing an empty session to be overwriting the active session in the database?

Thanks

Comment: I've looked at it a few times and I can't see the code where you get the and pass `$sessionData` to `write()`. Is it there and I'm just not seeing it, or is it invoked automatically on `__destruct()`?

Comment: Hi Jared, it's automatically handled by PHP. The class itself implements the `SessionHandlerInterface` class in PHP 5.4

Comment: Are you doing something [along these lines](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.session.savehandler.dbtable.html)?

Comment: closish - not not using Zend\Session though - even though there's not docs for it!

Comment: I can't tell if you're indicating you have other session-handling code you're not showing us. Are you logging? Write some information out to a log file and take a look at what's being seen.

Comment: I did some debugging and print_r (to see what the sql was doing), and write is being called with an empty session_data on a page load, hence the correct data in the database is being overwritten. There's only one session-handling code implemented, that's it.